# Netbeans how to break on exception on c++ project

Tags: c++, netbeans-8

In Netbeans 8, I'm debugging a C++ project. But I dont seem to find where to config gdb to "break on exceptions".

I go to main menu "Tools" -> "Options" -> "C/C++" -> tab "Debugging Options". Nothing found. Could this be a bug? (The options dialog is different than for a Java project).

(In Eclipse CDT, when debugging, there's a way to access the gdb session to manually issue a "catch throw", there is no such thing in Netbeans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naa, found it, in Menu Windows -> Debugging -> Debugging Console.

Then you can issue the "catch throw" there.